# c# Windows update API windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-update

This is a simple question, I've used the old wuapilib.dll for windows 7, but I'm unable to find anything to use to programatically call / use windows updates in Windows 10. Did Microsoft do away with this functionality?

Comment: WUApi.dll still works with Windows 10, but I think the new Delivery Optimization concept (Peer-to-Peer) introduced with Windows 10 might affect a few features of the API. (The WebProxy option seems broken according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894254/why-isnt-iupdatesessionwebproxy-working-on-windows-10))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use WUApi in Windows 10. Just add the reference.

The path is `C:\Windows\System32\wuapi.dll`