# Windows update is already installed (or newer patch applied)

Tags: windows, winapi, patch

I need to determine, if some Windows updates - KB's are installed on target computers.

*For example*, I have a computer with KB3185303. KB3033929 is already enough for product that I want to install. So, when I check patches on computer with `wmic qfe get hotfixid` - it says that kb is not installed and it'is right: according to MS patches list, KB3185303 includes KB3033929.

When try to install KB3033929 with `wusa.exe` it fails with code 2359302 (already installed https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/938205/windows-update-error-code-list).

*So, my question is*: is there any cases to check if update that I need is installed *OR* update that includes what I need is installed (without downloading target .msu file)?

Comment: I guess you could use code similar to that posted in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42894254/886887) to perform a Microsoft Update scan to see whether that particular update is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears Microsoft has updated that page since you posted and no longer lists that error code. Stack Overflow questions like this one are one of the few ways to find out what this code means. :P